# Add currency/dollar prefix to Input box in react/reactstrap?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

```
import { Input} from "reactstrap";
```

Want to add prefix to Input like "$", I didnt find any documentation on official site/documentation

[image]

Comment: I don't think input of type `number` here can accept `$` symbols ...

Comment: How about using dollar icon as a background of input?

Answer (score 2):

use this code:

```
  <InputGroup>
    <InputGroupText>
      $
    </InputGroupText>
    <Input placeholder="username" />
  </InputGroup>
```

https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/components-inputgroup--input-group